# Get, add up, and write all values ​to elements of a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a code like this:

```
<div class='true' value='1'/>
<div class='false' value='2'/>
<div class='true' value='3'/>
<div id='check'>Check my score</div>
Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

My question is how to get all the values ​​from the `<div>`s with the class `.true` and add them together ​​(1 + 3 = 4), then write `4` in the `.total` when I click on `check`?

What I've tried so far is:

```js
function checkscore(){
  // where I was stuck to add all the values
};

// I can only get the value and write it in the console
$(function() {
    $('#check').click(function(){
        var values = $('.true').map(function(i,v) {
            return v.value;
        }).get(); 
        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

```html
    <div class='true' value='1'/>
    <div class='false' value='2'/>
    <div class='true' value='3'/>
    <div id='check'>Check my score</div>
    Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. [help] [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vanilla javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let sum = 0;
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.true').forEach(function(el) {
    sum += parseInt(el.getAttribute('value'));
  });
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
});
```

```html
<div class='true' value='1'/>
<div class='false' value='2'/>
<div class='true' value='3'/>
<div id='check'>Check my score</div>
Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

Vanilla javascript using reduce:

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.true')].reduce( (acc, item) => {
    return acc + parseInt(item.getAttribute('value'));
  }, 0);
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = result;
});
```

```html
<div class='true' value='1'/>
<div class='false' value='2'/>
<div class='true' value='3'/>
<div id='check'>Check my score</div>
Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

**Note:** `[...document.querySelectorAll('.true')]` will spread the HTMLCollection object into an array.

---

Jquery:

```js
$('#check').click(function() {
  let sum = 0;
  
  $('.true').each(function(el) {
    sum += parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
  });
  $('#total').html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='true' value='1'/>
<div class='false' value='2'/>
<div class='true' value='3'/>
<div id='check'>Check my score</div>
Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

Comment: Alright this is what i looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, this is wrong:

```
<div class='true' value='1'/>
```

You should write this instead:

```
<div class='true' value='1'></div>
```

So what you're going to do first is to add an event listener to the `<div>`.
Then get the list of all `<div>`s with the class `true`.
Next, get their values by using `element.getAttribute('value')` and convert it to a number by using `parseInt()`.

Here is your code:

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener("click", function() {
   let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("true");
   
   let total = 0;
   
   for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     total = total + parseInt(elements[i].getAttribute('value'));
   }
   
   document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = Number(total);
});
```

```html
<div class='true' value='1'></div>
<div class='false' value='2'></div>
<div class='true' value='3'></div>
<div id='check'>Check my score</div>
Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need get value attribute by `attr()` function, and need create sum variable for total as below

```
function checkscore(){
  // where I was stuck to add all the values
  // I can only get the value and write it in the console
        var sum = 0;
        var values = $('.true').map(function(i,v) {

            var acc = parseInt($(v).attr('value'));
            sum += acc;
            //return acc;
        }).get(); 
        console.log( sum );
        $('#total').text(sum);
};
```

```js
function checkscore(){
  // where I was stuck to add all the values
  // I can only get the value and write it in the console
        var sum = 0;
        var values = $('.true').map(function(i,v) {
             
            var acc = parseInt($(v).attr('value'));
            sum += acc;
            //return acc;
        }).get(); 
        console.log( sum );
        $('#total').text(sum);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='true' value='1'/>
    <div class='false' value='2'/>
    <div class='true' value='3'/>
    <div id='check' onclick='checkscore();'>Check my score</div>
    Your score is: <div id='total'/>
```